Power BI relationship problem with date table
I have a Sales Fact table which includes the dates for orders, I created another table Dim Calender for seperate dates and connected this dim calender Dates with the sales fact table Dates, but this relationship is not working. When I make line chart between the sales from fact table and date column from the Dim Calender table, I see nothing on the chart, I have tried getting these two columns in the matrix form, but still on matrix i see no dates, but if i put only date from calender dim table into the field of matrix then  i see dates, I assume this is happeing because of the relationship between the dim calender and sales fact table. I have tried to debugg it but i am not able to find the problem. I am attaching the images of matrix below. If anyone has ever encounterd this problem before please guide me! Thank you so much!
For more information I have also tried using filter in both directions, but got nothing.
I have tried checking out the relationships in every possible way, but i am not able to debug this issue. I want to ask if anyone has every encounted it before, if yes please guide me!

Do your dates have time values in them?
